# QGIS user interactive map

Tags: qgis

I am doing a class project on QGIS. I just have some questions on it.

I would like to know if we can create a map which have several layers and buttons where user can click on his preferred parameters and a pop-up box appears asking him some questions.Later it shows user only desired layers.

Also I would like to know if we can add a button which calls an external python code and displays its output results as other layer in the map.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes that each Question should contain only one question. Please [edit] your Question to contain one question, and to provide more details on what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me this is subject of some special Python plugin. Some one should develop such plugin for you. See Python plugin API http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/